# R + tm package + text mining + html / web pages not vectorizing properly

Tags: html, r, text-mining, tm

I am taking my first shot at using R for text mining, and am following a tutorial posted here:  http://www.rexamine.com/2014/06/text-mining-in-r-automatic-categorization-of-wikipedia-articles/

I am not sure if the tm package has been modified, or what else may be the issue, but when I attempt to use the tm_map() function on a function which calls on the stri_replace_all_regex function (listed in the example code below at "docs2"), I get the following error:

```
" Error in stri_replace_all_regex(x, "<.+?>", " ") : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)"
```

I have been able to perform the tm_map functions without issue...however, even though the corpus is showing up in RStudio as a VCorpus, it is not being recognized by tm as a vector.  I've even used "as.vector(MyVCorpus)" without any luck.
I need to find a way to remove the artifactual HTML encoding, as with it remaining, document is unintelligible.

Suggestions / ideas /work-arounds??

```
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(proxy)
wiki <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
titles <- c("List of Titles")
articles <- character(length(titles))

for (i in 1:length(titles)) {
    articles[i] <- stri_flatten(readLines(stri_paste(wiki, titles[i])), col = " ")
}

docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(articles))

docs2 <- tm_map(docs, function(x) stri_replace_all_regex(x, "<.+?>", " "))
docs3 <- tm_map(docs2, function(x) stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "\t", " "))

docs4 <- tm_map(docs3, PlainTextDocument)
docs5 <- tm_map(docs4, stripWhitespace)
docs6 <- tm_map(docs5, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs7 <- tm_map(docs6, removePunctuation)
docs8 <- tm_map(docs7, tolower)
```

Comment: I thought tm_map(doc3, PlainTextDocument) removes HTML coding?  Why do you need the stri expression?

Comment: A suggestion would be to wrap `x` into `as.character(x)`.

Comment: @lawyerR...it's not getting rid of HTML.  Looks identical before and after I use tm_map(doc, PlainTextDocument)

Comment: @lukeA.  Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: `tm_map(docs, function(x) stri_replace_all_regex(as.character(x), "<.+?>", " "))` didn't work?